# Sending large base64 image to socket.io server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I am trying to send an image encoded in `base64` to a socket.io server. Simply emitting it doesn't seem to work. However, sending shorter strings works fine, the problem is with sending a really long `base64` encoded image.

```
// this works
this.socket.emit('imageUpload', {captureType: "documentBack", data: "simple text"})

// this doesn't
this.socket.emit('imageUpload', {captureType: "documentBack", data: "really long base64 encoded image"})
```

I have a frontend built with React JS and backend built with Node.

Following the comment by @Zac, I've implemented `socket.io-stream` like the documentation instructs but I still can't see the request on the backend. The data appears to have been emitted from the client but I can't see the data on the event handler.

This is what I have so far:

```
// Client (React.js)
import ss from 'socket.io-stream';

stream = ss.createStream();

ss(this.socket).emit('imageUpload', this.stream, {
            captureType: 'documentBack',
            data: imageData,
        });




// Server (Node.js)

socket.on("imageUpload", (stream, imageData) => {
      console.log("Image uploaded");
      // console.log(stream);
      // console.log(imageData);
      socket.broadcast.to(sessionId).emit("imageDownload", imageData);
    });
```

Comment: did you try using [socket.io-stream](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-stream) ?

Comment: not yet. looking at it now. thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to send such large data via socket.io?  There is all sorts of proven technology for doing http uploads of large files, not so much for socket.io as this isn't really what socket.io is great at or designed for.  I'm sure you can hack it together over socket.io by chunking the data and reassembling, but why?

Comment: Because I need a real time action-reaction mechanism, I need the data automatically relayed to all subscribed listeners.

Comment: If you're trying to broadcast a large file, then you can `socket.emit()` a URL and code each client to then go fetch that URL using proven and simple http technology that works for arbitrarily large files.  You would just need to your web server to be able to serve that URL when requested.  socket.io is simply not the right tool for large uploads or downloads.

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense. Basically what you're trying to say is that I should send the file via a http `post`, then the server returns the url for the file's server location. I then `socket.emit(url)` to all listening subscribers who would then be prompted to download the file via http. Is that correct?